# ListView Header and Footer not appearing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have following listview within a content page. Data binds fine, but header and footer never appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<ContentPage.Content>
        <SearchBar x:Name="SearchFor"
            Placeholder="search for"
            Text="{Binding Path=SearchText}"
            TextChanged="OnValueChanged" 
            SearchButtonPressed="OnSearch" />

        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
Header="{Binding ItemID}"
Footer="{Binding SupplierItemDesc}">
<ListView.HeaderTemplate >
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
        Padding="10,5,5,10"
        BackgroundColor="Yellow">
      <Label Text="~~"/>
      <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
      <Label Text="~~"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.HeaderTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding RetailCurrencyCode}" Detail="{Binding RetailValue}"></TextCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

Even if I enable grouping template, it just won't show anything.

Comment: There has been a known bug (although for iOS) that the header has a `Height` of 0, could you try giving you `StackLayout` a height and see if it does something?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, I tried specifying 'Height' at both 'StackLayout' and 'Label' but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your DataTemplate in a ViewCell and give it a height:

```
<ListView.HeaderTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                Padding="10,5,5,10"
                BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="40">
                  <Label Text="~~"/>
                  <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                  <Label Text="~~"/>
            </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: we can't seem to have ViewCell within DataTemplate. It would give an exception of : _Value was an invalid value for HeaderTemplate_

Comment: I meant HeaderTemplate for above.

Comment: Yes, my mistake there. I was under the impression you needed grouped headers. Try giving your StackLayout a "HeightRequest" instead of Height. Height is a readonly property. I changed my code sample to reflect this.

Comment: I actually used HeighRequest and MinHeightRequest, both at stacklayout and label, but no success. I initially tried Group Header, but neither that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue.  What resolved this for me, I instantiated the object I am binding to in the view model constructor.  I believe it's because I am binding to an object that is null when binding using `<Label Text="{Binding .}"/>`.